# Handling wrapped exception in Camel

Tags: exception, apache-camel

```
class MyRouteBuilder extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    public void configure() throws Exception {

       //initialize camel context here

       onException(ChildException.class)
    .process(new ChildExceptionHandler())
    .handled(true)
    .to(errorURI);

       onException(ParentException.class)
    .process(new ParentExceptionHandler())
    .handled(true)
    .to(errorURI);

       from(startURI)
       .processRef("someBeanID")
       //other processing here
    }
}
```

Now my "someBeanID" throws ChildException while processing, but ParentExceptionHandler is being invoked for that. Code snippet in "someBeanID" is as below

```
try {
   //some processing
   throws new ParentException();
} catch (ParentException e) {
     throw new ChildException(e);  //being handled by ParentExceptionHandler (why?? should be ChildExceptionHandler??)
     throw new ChildException();  //being handled by ChildExceptionHandler (should be)
}
```

It seems that whenever we wrap any exception, Camel automatically finds the actual wrapped exception and invokes handler for that, instead of invoking handler for wrapper exception. Why is this? Is there any problem in my code ??

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Finally resolved....Refer to [this](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Implementing_Enterprise_Integration_Patterns/files/BasicPrinciples-ExceptionHandling-ExClause.html)

> When trapping multiple exceptions, the order of the onException clauses is significant. Apache Camel initially attempts to match the thrown exception against the first clause. If the first clause fails to match, the next onException clause is tried, and so on until a match is found. Each matching attempt is governed by the following algorithm:
>
> If the thrown exception is a chained exception (that is, where an exception has been caught and rethrown as a different exception), the most nested exception type serves initially as the basis for matching. This exception is tested as follows:
>
> If the exception-to-test has exactly the type specified in the onException clause (tested using instanceof), a match is triggered.
>
> If the exception-to-test is a sub-type of the type specified in the onException clause, a match is triggered.
>
> If the most nested exception fails to yield a match, the next exception in the chain (the wrapping exception) is tested instead. The testing continues up the chain until either a match is triggered or the chain is exhausted.